# How to implement two similar views efficiently in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've two exactly similar views which I show in a two segmented control. Refer to image below. The differences between these two views is the parameter which I send to backend to fetch the values and the title. Even the returned values are same.

I've referred to some tutorial which cycles from one view to another when segment is selected .

I've ended up with two files with exactly same code. How to optimise this implementation so that I can implement with one piece of code only.

The two contained VCs have exactly same code to fetch values from backend and display. I've only one function which I've used in both VCs to fetch but there are other code sections such as Tableview delegations and other codes which are common to both.

In storyboard both are duplicate as well.

Is there anyway I can make it more efficient?

[image]

Comment: Make both view controllers inherit from a common superclass? Or even use two instances of the very same view controller class? Impossible to be specific, because _you_ have not been specific — your question is about code, but you have shown _zero_ code.

Comment: You may be interested to read about the code reuse strategy of [class inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a case for making your two view controllers be subclasses of a common superclass.

Or it could be even simpler: make them two instances of the *same* view controller class, which knows what to do because you pass a parameter at creation time telling it what to do.

For example, my Albumen app uses four view controllers, which differ primarily just in what query they perform on the user's music library. So I've elected to make them four instances of *one* view controller class, with an enum property saying which query it is, and any other varying functionality determined through switch statements on that enum.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create only 1 VC ( In IB and code ) , put all the logic inside it and either

1- Add once instance / container of it to the MainVC and manage the process of selecting a segment to reload the content ( Recommended )

2- Add 2 instances of it to the MainVC and manage hide/show when the segment is selected